# How can we Override ActionController in rails to common out certain methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have the authentication code to be available over several Controllers. So I thought of putting the Authentication code in to a SuperClass and then make all the other controllers extend this SuperClass. I then got to know that we can add it in the ActionController class itself. How can we do that? Is  there a way to change the pre defined class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the methods to the ApplicationController class which lives in app/controllers/application_controller.rb and is the direct superclass of all your project's controllers (assuming you created your controllers with script/generate and did not change the superclass).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed seeing that there's already a ApplicationController class.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask- In the Routes.rb file do we have to use "ApplicationController" to specify the controller being used?

Answer (score 1):

Actually all your controllers should already inherit from `ApplicationController`, which in turn inherits from `ActionController::Base`. And including authentication code into `ApplicationController` is quite idiomatic, really.

Comment: I do know that code can be added into ApplicationController. But how do we do it? Do we create a new script file and declare a ApplicationController Class there? I am new to Rails so not much idea of how it can be done.

Comment: just check application_controller.rb (see sepp2k's answer for the path). and also make sure that all your other controllers inherit from ApplicationController.

Answer (score 0):

All controllers already extend `ApplicationController`, so simply add an authorize method and a `before_filter` calling that method in your `ApplicationController` and you'll be all set for all your controllers.